# Shapefile to MDB with custom field structure

Tags: ms-access, shapefile

I have a Shapefile with 80.000 polygons that they are grouped by a specific field called "**OTA**".

I wanted to convert each Shapefile (it's attribute table) to mdb database (not Personal Geodatabase) with one table in it with the same name as the Shapefile and with a given field structure.
In the code I used I had to load on Python 2 new modules:
`pypyodbc` and `adodbapi`

The first module was used to create the mdb file for each shapefile and the second to create the table in the mdb and fill the table with the data from the attribute table of the shapefile.

The code I came up with is the following:

```
import pypyodbc
import adodbapi
Folder = ur'C:\TestPO' # Folder to save the mdbs
FD = Folder+ur'\27ALLPO.shp' # Shapefile
Map = u'PO' # Map type
N = u'27' # Prefecture
OTAList = sorted(set([row[0] for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(FD,('OTA'))]))
cnt = 0
for OTAvalue in OTAList:
    cnt += 1
    dbname = N+OTAvalue+Map
    pypyodbc.win_create_mdb(Folder+'\\'+dbname+'.mdb')
    conn_str = (r"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source="+Folder+"\\"+dbname+ur".mdb;")
    conn = adodbapi.connect(conn_str)
    crsr = conn.cursor()
    SQL = "CREATE TABLE ["+dbname+"] ([FID] INT,[AREA] FLOAT,[PERIMETER] FLOAT,[KA_PO] VARCHAR(10),[NOMOS] VARCHAR(2),[OTA] VARCHAR(3),[KATHGORPO] VARCHAR(2),[KATHGORAL1] VARCHAR(2),[KATHGORAL2] VARCHAR(2),[LABEL_PO] VARCHAR(8),[PHOTO_45] VARCHAR(14),[PHOTO_60] VARCHAR(10),[PHOTO_PO] VARCHAR(8),[POLY_X_CO] DECIMAL(10,3),[POLY_Y_CO] DECIMAL(10,3),[PINAKOKXE] VARCHAR(11),[LANDTYPE] DECIMAL(2,0));"
    crsr.execute(SQL)
    conn.commit()
    with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(FD,['FID','AREA','PERIMETER','KA_PO','NOMOS','OTA','KATHGORPO','KATHGORAL1','KATHGORAL2','LABEL_PO','PHOTO_45','PHOTO_60','PHOTO_PO','POLY_X_CO','POLY_Y_CO','PINAKOKXE','LANDTYPE'],'"OTA" = \'{}\''.format(OTAvalue)) as cur:
        for row in cur:
            crsr.execute("INSERT INTO "+dbname+" VALUES ("+str(row[0])+","+str(row[1])+","+str(row[2])+",'"+row[3]+"','"+row[4]+"','"+row[5]+"','"+row[6]+"','"+row[7]+"','"+row[8]+"','"+row[9]+"','"+row[10]+"','"+row[11]+"','"+row[12]+"',"+str(row[13])+","+str(row[14])+",'"+row[15]+"',"+str(row[16])+");")
            conn.commit()
    crsr.close()
    conn.close()
    print (u'«'+OTAvalue+u'» ('+str(cnt)+u'/'+str(len(OTAList))+u')')
```

Executing this code took about 5 minutes to complete the task for about 140 mdbs.
As you can see, I execute an "INSERT INTO" statement for each record of the shapefile.

Is this the correct way (and probably the fastest) or should I collect all the statements for each "OTA" and execute them all together?

Comment: If it's one time procedure, I would import all files to one or few MDB (depending on data size, 2GB limit) , and then created separate MDBs based on imported tables, it will be easier than create table structure using VBA.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think anyone's going to write your code for you, but if you try some VBA yourself, and tell us what happened and what worked and what you're stuck on, you'll get a great response.

Saying that - to start with I don't see any reason to use VB6 when you can use VBA right inside your mdb file.

Use DIR command and possibly FileSystemObject to loop through all DBFs in a given folder, or use FileDialog object to select multiple files at one go

Then process each file with

```
DoCmd.TransferDatabase command 
    TransferType:=acImport, _
    DatabaseType:="dBASE III", _
    DatabaseName:="your-dbf-filepath", _
    ObjectType:=acTable, _
    Source:="Source", _
    Destination:="your-newtbldbf"
```

Finally process each dbf import with a make table query

Look at results and see what might have to be changed based on field types before and after.

Then .... edit your post and let us know how it went

Answer (score 0):

In theory you could do something like this by searching the directory the DBF files reside in, writing those filenames to a table, then loop through the table and, for each filename, scan the DBF for tables and their fieldnames/datatypes and create those tables in your MDB.  You could also bring in all the data from the tables, all within a series of loops.

In theory, you could.

In practice, you can't.  And you can't, because DBF and MDB support different data types that aren't compatible.

I *suppose* you could create a "crosswalk" table such that for each datatype in DBF there is a corresponding, hand-picked datatype in MDB and use that when you're creating the table, but it's probably going to either fail to import some of the data or import corrupted data.  And that's assuming you can open a DBF for reading the same way you can open an MDB for reading.  Can you run OpenDatabase on a DBF from inside Access?  I don't even have the answer to that.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recommend that you do this.  The reason that you're doing it is because you want to keep the structure as similar as possible when migrating from dBase/FoxBase to Access.  However, the file structure is different between them.

As you are aware, each .DBF ("Database file") file is a table, and the folder or directory in which the .DBF files reside constitutes the "database".  With Access, all the tables in one database are in one .MDB ("Microsoft Database") file.

If you try to put each .DBF file in a separate .MDB file, you will have no end of trouble getting the .MDB files to interact.  Access treats different .MDB files as different databases, not different tables in the same database, and you will have to do strange things like link all the separate databases just to have basic relational functionality.  (I tried this about 25 years ago with Paradox files, which are also a one-file-per-table structure.  It didn't take me long to decide it was easier to get used to the one-file-per-database concept.)  Do yourself a favor, and migrate all of the .DBF files in one folder into a single .MDB file.

As for what you ought to do with your code, I'd first suggest that you use ADO rather than DAO.  But if you want to stick with DAO because you've been using it, then you need to have one connection to the dBase file and another to the Access database.  As far as I can tell, you don't have the dBase connection.  I've never tried what you're doing before, but I doubt you can use a SQL statement to select directly from a .dbf file in the way you're doing.  (I could be wrong, though; Microsoft has come up with stranger things over the years.)

It would